RC discharging equation/natural response

Why do we make this particular assumption when trying to derive the capacitor discharging equation/rc natural response?
If we don't and solve the equation just by assuming Ir=Ic, then the equation turns out to become e^(t/rc) which wouldn't correctly predict the graph. I understand that it doesn't matter which direction we assume current to be in KCL and the solving it would tell us the right direction, but in this case this assumption changes the final equation and there's no means to deduce anything else from the final equation. Please give me a better picture of what is going on.

For clarification, this is the differential equation we end up with usually, using the above mentioned assumption.

Please clarify what you mean by $i_R$ and $i_C$. The entire circuit has only one current, $I$.

The capacitor and resistor current are in the same direction which, for conventional current (flow of positive charge), is the direction of $i_R$.


Why do we make this particular assumption when trying to derive the
capacitor discharging equation/rc natural response?

You can choose whatever direction you want, just make sure that the voltage and current share the same direction for each component (see below)

If we don't and solve the equation just by assuming Ir=Ic, then the
equation turns out to become e^(t/rc) which wouldn't correctly predict
the graph

You can let $i_R = i_C = i$, it's just that you'll have to let $v_R = - v_C$
The corresponding equation would be
$$i_R = i_C$$
$$v_R + v_C = 0$$
where $v_R = R\;i_R$ and $i_C = C\dfrac{dv_C}{dt}$
The convention for the circuit laws of the basic electrical components is that current's direction is always chosen to flow from the positive side to the negative side of the voltage i.e. if $v = \phi(A) - \phi(B)$, then the current flows from $A$ to $B$. Your mistake was not to change the sign of their voltage accordingly

Indeed you are right with your two equations:
$$\begin{align}
  i_C+i_R&=0\\[5pt]
\Rightarrow C\frac {dv}{dt} + \frac1R v &= 0
\end{align}$$
And if we proceed from there we get:
$$\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \frac {dv}{dt} &=  -\frac1{RC}\,v
  \\[5pt]
\Rightarrow  v(t) &= A\,e^{-t/(RC)} \quad\text{for some constant $A$} 
\end{align}$$
If that doesn't correctly predict the graph, as you write, then the graph is wrong! (But you also mention $e^{(t/rc)}$ somewhere, which has of course the wrong exponent, so that must be your typo, I guess...)

I'm sorry for the confusion, but what i meant was, when we consider the equation Ir=Ic, the second equation becomes C(dv/dt)=v/R. Solving this would give us e^(t/rc) which clearly isn't the same as e^-(t/rc).

But why would you use $I_r=I_c$?! The blue arrows in your drawing clearly indicate that  $I_r=-I_c$.
